# log to redshift using log4net's adonetappender

Tags: .net, log4net, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to log to my redshift server using log4net's builtin adonetappender. When the timestamp field is removed the log will successfully be saved. However, the format of the timestamp seems to be causing it to fail. I have tried many different formats that match what redshift claims to support.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<!-- This section contains the log4net configuration settings -->
<log4net>

<!-- Define some output appenders -->

<appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
  <immediateFlush value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
</appender>

<appender name="RedshiftAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection,System.Data,version=1.0.3300.0,publicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089,culture=neutral" />
  <connectionString value="Driver={Amazon Redshift (x86)};..." />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO hep_config.server_log (tm,src,lvl,msg) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="$1" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date{yyyyMMdd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="$2" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="128" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%thread" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="$3" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="64" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%level" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="$4" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%message" />
  </parameter>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="RedshiftAppender" />
</root>

</log4net>

</configuration>
```

Comment: updating question description, as it appears that the problem is related to the format of the timstamp. When I remove the timestamp, the log is inserted.

Comment: Are you sure the format you are using is a valid timestamp for Redshift? Based on the examples provided in the documentation, it doesn't look like it. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Date_and_time_literals.html

Comment: good point! ... though even when I updated that it is still giving me the same error, namely: "System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" ... editted to show a proper date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and couldn't get it working with the Redshift driver. However, the [PostgreSQL ODBC Driver](https://odbc.postgresql.org/) does work. Try the following:

Change your connection string to use the [PostgreSQL ODBC Driver](https://odbc.postgresql.org/). Note I'm on 64-bit windows, so you will need to adjust the driver based on your version.

```
<connectionString value="Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};..." />
```

Change your layout for the DateTime to use RawUtcTimeStampLayout.

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.RawUtcTimeStampLayout" />
```

**NOTE:** [Timestamp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Datetime_types.html) values in Redshift are [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

**UPDATE**

I was able to get it to work with the Redshift driver. The MSDN documentation for [OdbcCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters(v=vs.100).aspx) states:

> When CommandType is set to Text, the .NET Framework Data Provider for
>   ODBC does not support passing named parameters to an SQL statement or
>   to a stored procedure called by an OdbcCommand. In either of these
>   cases, use the question mark (?) placeholder.

and

> The order in which OdbcParameter objects are added to the
>   OdbcParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of
>   the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Using this information you can try the following:

```
<commandText value="INSERT INTO log.log_test(tm,src,lvl,msg) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" />
```

At this point it doesn't matter what you name the parameters, as the order of the parameters matter. I did continue to use RawUtcTimeStampLayout, but I changed the dbType to string.

Comment: while this isn't quite an answer since it's using a different driver, it's about as close as it appears I'll get ... I need to verify redshift supports using the postgresql odbc driver ... if I don't get a better answer before end of bounty I'll award it here

Comment: Thanks for the help! one caveat ... the RawUtcTimeStampLayout does not seem to record subseconds!

Answer (score 0):

You can define the timestamp format as part of your [COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html#r_COPY-parameters) command.

Use the following flag:

> TIMEFORMAT [AS] {'timeformat_string' | 'auto' | 'epochsecs' |
>   'epochmillisecs' } If no TIMEFORMAT is specified, the default format
>   is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.

Comment: sorry ... I never actually execute a copy command within my code, I assume neither is log4net since it's using a prepared query ... I'm not sure how this applies to the question at all?

Comment: It is recommended to COPY data into Redshift and not INSERT it. It allows much faster ingestion time and you can put many more log entries as it is done in parallel with COPY and serially with INSERT. 
Once you have your log files, you can copy them to S3 and then COPY them to Redshift.

Comment: while I agree with you for large files (and yes, we do exactly this when loading the data warehouse), this is real-time logging using the adonetappender from log4net ... what you are recommending simply doesn't apply.